# using jQueryUI sortable list with forms

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, forms, post

I'm using jQueryUI to create a sortable list, and the UI part works great in that I can sort the items as desired on the web page.  I can't figure out, though, how the order of the sorted list is included in the POST.  I'm a total noob with javascript so please forgive me if this is really simple.

Here are the relevant portions of my html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("jquery", "1");
  google.load("jqueryui", "1");
  function OnLoad(){
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({ axis: "y", containment: "#ballot", scroll: false });
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
  }
  google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
</script>

[...]

<form method="POST" action="/vote">
<input type="hidden" name="key" value="{{ election.key }}">
<input type="hidden" name="uuid" value="{{ uuid }}">
<div id="ballot" class="center">
<ol id="sortable" class="rankings">
  <li class="ranking">Jamie</li>
  <li class="ranking">Joanie</li>
  <li class="ranking">Morley</li>
  <li class="ranking">Frank</li>
  <li class="ranking">Larry</li>
</ol>
</div>
</form>
```

How can the order of Jamie, Joanie, Morley, Frank, and Larry be encoded in the POST?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the method `.serialize` on your sortable object : http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable#method-serialize

`$( "#sortable" ).sortable('serialize')` will give you an ajax submittable array of items. Just assign it to an input box if you are not using ajax. Or simply pass it into your data array if using ajax

**EDIT**
Example here : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/KeAer/2/

As the jquery docs note, for this to work your elements need to have ids in the form of `set_number` (e.g. rank_1, rank_2). So I've modified your HTML

Just remove the `return false` in the form and the serialized value will be set to the input box on form submission

Comment: John, I'm not using AJAX.  To assign it to an input box, would I do something like this?: <input type="hidden" name="order" value=$( "#sortable" ).serialize()>

Comment: I've edited my reply with details on usage and an example. The correct way to use it is `$('.sel').sortable('serialize')`

Answer (score 7):

Another option is to just have a hidden input form field with the ID value for the item as the value and the same name.  Then submit the form after sorting stops.  The values will all be available in the posted data in the order they were after the sort.

I do something like this:

```
$(".sortable").each(function () {
    $(this).sortable({
        update: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).closest("form").trigger("onsubmit");
        }
    });
});
```

And the form looks like this:

```
<form ...>
<ul class="sortable">

        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Some info here<input id="id_name" name="id_name" type="hidden" value="1" /></li>

        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Some more info<input id="id_name" name="id_name" type="hidden" value="2" /></li>

</ul>
</form>
```