# JQuery sortable/selectable plugin with drag'n'drop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

First of all, I'm not a JS developer, so I apologize if I'm asking a rather too general, previously asked or complex question. The functionality I'm searching for is that I'd like to have two HTML lists, on the load the first one is empty and I want user to pick the items he like from the second list and drag them into the first one (which should be sortable so user can set the order he likes). Is there a easy to use plugin for it?

I really like the idea and look of those two plugins..

http://www.emposha.com/javascript/fcbkcomplete.html

http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin

There are doing something different, but those "bubbles" in textfield are a great way to handle it (from UX point of view). Just to be able to have an empty text field, available bubbles below it and to be able to drag them into the text field, just those user wants (no autocomplete functionality, just draging from some list of them, maybe sorting in text field available would be nice). Maybe there's a similar plugin to do that.

Another thing is, it's a part of a form so I need to be able to send those picked up elements to the server with the form, each with it's position. I know, I am asking too much but any help will help me.

Comment: I'm sorry to be rude here, but you're suggesting: `jquery` and are using the keyword `sortable`. Have you actually tried searching for that? As searching on google for `jquery sortable`, the very first result links to: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/ which, by your description, contains all you need. ?!

Comment: I know, you're right, but I was hoping someone would know a nicer solution. I don't know much about javascript in practise, I'm a Ruby developer. Of course I know `jquery-ui sortable`, but it's not fitting my needs perfectly. My apologies, I'm just asking.

Comment: If your list issn't to long, why not just use a `<select size="5" multiple="multiple">...`? Or do you need the *nice* UI?

Comment: Because of few things. I need sorting (the items are actually methods on the server which would run on the object in the exact order after submiting the form), nice UI is needed because this functionality will be operated by non-technical persons, so it needs to be visual and with no distractions what exactly they are calling (the reason for two lists, one with options, one with those selected, drag'n'drop for ease of use).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Jquery UI

Here are links for demos

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

EDIT

I think all you want is this

http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#shopping-cart

Comment: You're right. That "shopping-cart" is the functionality I'm looking for. But I need to be able to send it easily with the form to the server (the second reason I like those autocomplete plugins mentioned above, because the are using text field, those bubbles could be serialized into one string and processed on the server, that would be awesome if it would be possible to do it like this).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe jQuery UI would work for you; it is composed of several handy helper functions.

Take a look at sortable with connected lists: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists

Comment: [sortable/#empty-lists](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#empty-lists) This would to the thing as I can see. But I have no idea how to send it back to the server =(

Comment: Take a look at this answer; it explains how to use the plugin with a form: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131460/using-jqueryui-sortable-list-with-forms